# Django errors get overlapped, can't style them

Tags: python, html, css, django

I have a form and I decided to handle it manually. My form is actually from 2 forms, but that's not important. Thing is, that when I want to display the errors at the bottom of my form, they get overlapped on top of each other. I wanted to show one at a time, so I tried to use padding with overflow hidden for the form, but doesn't seem to work. Any style I apply won't work, except for margins.

```css
.alert {
    margin-top: 45% !important;
  }
  #errors {
    padding: 20px !important;
  }
```

```html
{% if form1.errors %}
                {% for field in form1 %}
                    {% for error in field.errors %}
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                            <strong id="errors">{{ error|escape }}</strong>
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endfor %}
                {% for error in form1.non_field_errors %}
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
            {% if form2.errors %}
                {% for field in form2 %}
                    {% for error in field.errors %}
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                            <strong id="errors">{{ error|escape }}</strong>
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endfor %}
                {% for error in form2.non_field_errors %}
                    <div class="alert  alert-danger">
                        <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
```

[image]

Comment: You probably have some other CSS which is setting an absolute position for alert or errors. Note, you certainly shouldn't have more than one element with id=errors; ids must be unique, you should probably use a class instead.

Comment: @DanielRoseman position was the issue. Thank you!